# How to write variables inside Query language?

Tags: java

**Example:**

```
String s1;
String q = "select * from EntryByTitle where booktitle='"+s1+"'";
```

here in query statement why +s1+ is used in the syntax. As s1 is string, so it should be '"s1"'. But why '"+s1+"' is written in project.

Comment: are you using any framework like hibernate, or simply using jdbc?

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: The compiler by default accepts string values inside the '" "". But when we have to pass many such values we should substitute the value contained in some variable. If we explicitly pass '"s1"' the compiler takes that as a string. But thats not what we want to pass to the database, we need to pass the value contained in the variable. Thus to help compiler differentiate a variable containing a string and an explicit string passed. we use the +s1+ between the '" "'.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and a bind parameter. This usually takes the form

```
String q = "select * from EntryByTitle where booktitle=?";
String bookTitle = "";
Connection conn = null;
try {
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(q)) {
        ps.setString(1, bookTitle);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("booktitle"));
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```